# How to offload modular exponentiation to Octeon II Crypto Coprocessor

Tags: cryptography, hardware, offloading

Is it possible to offload modular exponentiation required in RSA and Diffie-Hellman to Hardware (Crypto Co-processor) that comes with Octeon II platform.

In some document, I have seen that Octeon II platform do support that. But, I am not getting how to do that. What macros to be used etc?

Can anyone please provide me with some pointer?

Comment: WRT to the runtime system, I presume you are talking a native C/C++ application? Please include the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

These look like proprietary functions to me. In that case you can these libraries in proprietary SDKs. In this case the [OCTEON Development Kits](http://www.cavium.com/octeon_software_develop_kit.html) page specifies:

> Libraries: ‘C’ acceleration libraries for compression/decompression, pattern matching, **encryption/decryption**, Robust Header Compression

Generally *encryption/decryption* should be seen as a substitute for the word *cryptography* as most people don't know that encryption/decryption is just part of the crypto spectrum.

For more info, please contact Cavium.